# "tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully" when loading a model in Streamlit app

Tags: streamlit, tarfile

I have the following line of code:

```py
model = pickle.load(open('saved_models/model.pkl', 'rb'))
```

```py
ReadError: file could not be opened successfully

Traceback:

File "C:\Users\ovist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 556, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)File "F:\Licenta\pages\models_page.py", line 44, in <module>
    model = pickle.load(open('saved_models/model.pkl', 'rb'))File "C:\Users\ovist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\pickle_utils.py", line 39, in deserialize_model_from_bytecode
    with tarfile.open(fileobj=b, mode="r") as archive:File "C:\Users\ovist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tarfile.py", line 1625, in open
    raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully")
```

The command works fine in a local python script instead of streamlit app.

Note: I am using Python 3.9.12

Comment: Do you use the same Python version locally and on the remote server?

Comment: Yes! I solved the problem by using the specific functions from tf.keras to save and load the model.